# Laravel / Cannot access protected property Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$items

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, eloquent

I'm still learning Laravel and I'm using eloquent to run my queries. In my application a user can belong to one circle. The circle contains repositories, which in turn contains items. I am trying to fetch all of the items which belong to various repositories within one circle.

User Model:

```
public function circle () {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Circle');
}
```

Circle Model:

```
public function users () {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User');
}

public function repositories () {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Repository');
}
```

Repository Model:

```
public function items () {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Item');
}

public function circle () {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Circle');
}
```

Item Model:

```
public function repository () {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Repository');
}
```

Here is the markup where I am trying to iterate over all items:

```
  @foreach($items as $item)
      <span>{{ $item->name }}</span>
  @endforeach
```

My controller responsible for handling the route is here:

```
function library () {
  $user = Auth::user();
  $circle = $user->circle;
  $repositories = $circle->repositories;
  $items = $repositories->items;
  return View('pages.library', compact(['user', 'circle', 'items']));
}
```

As of right now I can retrieve 2 repositories belonging to a circle but I cannot retrieve the multiple items that belong to those 2 repositories. I have tried a @foreach on the repositories to run through both and push the items in an empty array but I only end up with the last item. Is there a query technique/step that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$repositories` is a collection not a model. So you shouldn't call the `$items` property prom it because it's protected.

I know that You looking for the items relation so... You need to itterate over the `$repositories` and the over the each `$repository` $item like:

```
@foreach($repositories as $repository)
    @foreach($repository->items as $item)
        <span>{{ $item->name }}</span>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And remove this from the controller:

`$items = $repositories->items;`

Comment: Thank you very much this worked. I am trying to understand this more clearly however. So... the instantiated object in the controller has access to its belongs to method. And making use of this method we can create a new instance of the associated model. However when we do the same for a hasMany we are retrieving a collection. So would you recommend me to avoid getting collections from collections, is that bad practice and should I have avoiding this kind of situation or ts this perfectly fine?

Comment: Would you recommend I put a 'circle_id' foreign key on my 'items' table? So that I can just grab all the items that are associated with the circle model in question rather than creating instances of the repositories and further boiling it down to the item instances, or is that bad practice?